# split or cut and assign values of a variable to another variable in unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk

My variable has value "test one two", i want them to be separated by " " and store in different variable.

```
#/usr/bin/ksh


var="test one two"
___________________________ command
    temp1 = test
    temp2 = one
    temp3 = two
```

Comment: This is one of those cases where we're being asked to implement a solution instead of provide a solution. I suspect if you told us what your larger application is and we helped you come up with a solution for it, this wouldn't even be a question. You tagged it with bash but your shebang says ksh - which are you REALLY using or can you use either one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ksh` you can use `read`:

```
var="test one two"
echo "$var" | read temp1 temp2 temp3
$ echo "$temp1"
test
$ echo "$temp2"
one
$ echo "$temp3"
two
```

Comment: Can this be done by not using echo? i want them to be stored and pass to next command like by using cut or awk?

Comment: I'm getting error "syntax error at line 5 : `<' unexpected" i'm working on hp-unix box

Comment: Ok HP-unix might be older `ksh`. Better to use the syntax I provided in my answer for that.

Comment: Even when using `awk` or `cut` you cannot avoid pipes in KSH. Only if you switch to BASH then you can avoid it using `<<<` herestring.

Comment: @anubhava you can avoid pipes in KSH just by using a here document, `read temp1 temp2 temp3 <<!<newline>$var<newline>!` instead of a here string.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton that is very helpful. Strangely on my OSX even `read temp1 temp2 temp3 <<< "$var"` worked.

Comment: I've no idea what shells support `<<<`, I've never had a reason to use it yet. I thought it was bash only but many bash features come from zsh and ksh93 so maybe this is one? I didn't downvote your answer by the way, must've been a drive-by :-).

Comment: @EdMorton You are correct (no surprises `:)`). [`<<<`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) or `Here-Strings` notation is available in `bash, zsh and ksh`. The reason it worked on Mac is because Mac's default shell is `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can use bash since you tagged your question with bash, this is probably what you really should do:

```
$ var="test one two"
$ temp=( $var )
$ echo "${temp[0]}"
test
$ echo "${temp[1]}"
one
$ echo "${temp[2]}"
two
```

but I suspect whatever script you're using this in is probably employing the wrong approach to solve whatever your larger problem is.